# JQuery can't find variable from separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, undefined

I am using the cakephp framework and I created 2 separate javascript files and placed them into my webroot/js folder.  The first javascript file contains modal dialog variables that contain the settings for the dialog boxes.  The second javascript file contains other click event handlers that post data to an action and then open up the dialog.

The problem I am having is that the second file calls a variable from the first file using
$*variablename* and I get an error saying varaibleName is not defined.

Some code is below to show you what I mean.
From the first file:

```
var $editSel = $("#editSel_dialog").dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 530,
    width: 800,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons:
    {
        "Cancel": function()
        {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

From the second file:

```
$('.neweditSel_dialog').live('click', function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

    var selected = [];

    $("#[id*=LocalClocks]").each(function()
    {
        if(false != $(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            var string = $(this).attr('id').replace('LocalClocks', '');
            string = string.substring(10);
            selected.push(string);
        }
    });

    if(0 === selected.length)
    {
        $selError.dialog('open');
        $selError.text('No Local Clocks Were Selected')
    }
    else
    {
        $.post('/LocalClocks/editSelected', { "data[Session][selected]": selected }, function(data)
        {
        });
        $editSel.load($(this).attr('href'), function ()
        {
            $editSel.dialog('open');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

This was working when I was using jquery-1.4.2.min.js, but I am using jquery1.7 now.
I also ended up putting the first file with all the variables inside of `$(document).ready(function(){});`  I tried putting the second file inside of a document.ready() function but that made no difference.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: it is the `$editSel` variable in the else clause that can't be found.

Comment: `$editSel`. Since its the only variable defined in the first file.

Comment: @techfoobar Ive seen plenty of people list code as examples when actually what theyre asking doesn't relate in any way.  It doesn't hurt to make sure.

Comment: In your HTML, is the script tag for the second file after the script tag for first one?

Comment: @JonTaylor - Thats true. I've seen quite a few cases like that too.

Comment: yes, I am declaring using HTML->Script in my default.ctp, jquery, then my first file and then my second.  I checked firebug and it the first file is loading before the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with an issue in scope. In javascript:

```
function foo() {
    var greet = "hi";
}

function bar() {
    console.log(greet); // will throw error
}
```

However:

```
var greet;
function foo() {
    greet = "hi";
}

function bar() {
    console.log(greet); // will log "hi"
}
```

You must define your variable in a common parent of both functions that need to access it. Unfortunately, since you do not use any modeling convention or framework, that is the window object ([why are global variables bad?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/)).

So, you must define `var $whateveryouneed` *before* and *outside of* both `$(document).ready`s.

Also, keep the `declaration` and `definition` seperate. Your definition instantiates a jQuery object, so you must encapsulate it inside a `$(document).ready()` (use `$(function() {})` instead):

```
var $editSel;
$(function () {
    $editSel = $("#editSel_dialog").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 530,
        width: 800,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons:
        {
            "Cancel": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using the cakephp framework.  I don't think there is a common parent because both files just pull out javascript from my view files.  But to test this out, I will combine both files than work from there.

Comment: _Javascript_ framework. Defining a global variable like in the updated answer should solve your problem, without combining the files.

Comment: Hey, you were right, changing the dialog settings into a function and then placing the global variable call `var $editSel` above the document.ready() call worked.  THanks for the help

Comment: No problem, take a look at those resources I posted, there are some good tips of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can guarantee the order in which handlers will be fired, which means that the document ready may be fired in different order than you expect. Is the variable you are trying to access in the second file a global variable?  Try to think about your variables scope as I would have thought this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee that one file will be loaded before the other. And you cannot guarantee that document.ready in one file will fire before the other.

Therefore, I suggest you wrap your code in functions and call them in a single document.ready handler in the order you need.

For example:

```
function initVariables(){
    window.$editSel = ... // your code from the first file here
}

function initHandlers(){
    // your code from the second file here
}
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initVariables();
    initHandlers();
});
```

You'll notice that I used the global `window` object to expose your variable. It would be even better if you used a common namespace for them.